# Oracle 12c: sql query return less result when it's used in a subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery, oracle-12c

I recently encountered a weird situation where i get different result from the same query by only changing its scope.

What i mean by changing the scope , is putting the query inside a subquery:

I have this query:

```
select * from my_function
```

It returns the correct result, but when it's used as a subquery it gives less result :

```
select * from (select * from my_function)
```

Please note that there is no filters nor limits on rows.

my_function is a function that return a dataset like this :

```
return anydataset pipelined using myType;
```

I'm wondering if there is some (hidden) parameter in oracle 12c that might limits the result of a query when it's used in a view or a sub-query , especially if this query is using a function as source.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide a test case? Could be a bug as well. This is something similar: *Bug 20004642 - Wrong results from query with TABLE() subquery and functions with binds (Doc ID 20004642.8)*

Comment: Sorry for being late, as you mentioned, i actually use TABLE() in my query , and to resolve the problem , rewrite the whole query without using it ,and  the problem was solved. Thanks @BalazsPapp